# Which constants can be ignored in Big O for time complexity - exponential cases?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

The obvious one is a constant on a linear term for example 2n, 4n and 8n are all just n or O(n).

But what about the exponential constant **1.6^n** and **2^n**.  In this case the constant seems to have a greater effect on the time complexity.

Also there is not really a convenient way to write a catch all for exponential time complexity.

**O(K^n)** perhaps.

In this [cheat sheet](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com), they seem to use **O(2^n)** does that mean that all exponential complexities should be written that way?

Probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.  The cheat sheet you linked to [here](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/) can not show all the different complexities so it picks the most common ones.

Simply put, if you have a function growing at `3 ^ n`.  It can not be classified as `2 ^ n` because it will break the definition of Big O.

The some what complex looking math that describes Big O is simply saying that it can't ever be bigger.  And also ignore linear growth constants.

```
f(n) ≤ c * g(n) whenever n ≥ n0
```

Answer (score 3):

You're right that 2n, 4n and 8n are all just O(n), and you're also right that O(1.6<sup>n</sup>) is not the same as O(2<sup>n</sup>). To understand why, we need to refer to the definition of big O notation.

The notation O(...) means a set of functions. A function f(n) is in the set O(g(n)) if and only if, for some constants c and n<sub>0</sub>, we have **f(n) ≤ c * g(n) whenever n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>**. Given this definition:

- The function f(n) = 8n is in the set O(n) because if we choose c = 8 and n<sub>0</sub> = 1, we have **8n ≤ 8 * n** for all n ≥ 1.
- The function f(n) = 2<sup>n</sup> is **not** in the set O(1.6<sup>n</sup>), because whichever c and n<sub>0</sub> we choose, **2<sup>n</sup> > c * 1.6<sup>n</sup>** for some sufficiently large n. We can choose n > log<sub>2</sub> c + n<sub>0</sub> log<sub>2</sub> 1.6 for a concrete counterexample.
- Note however that f(n) = 1.6<sup>n</sup> **is** in the set O(2<sup>n</sup>), because **1.6<sup>n</sup> ≤ 1 * 2<sup>n</sup>** for all n ≥ 1.

For a "catch-all" way of writing exponential complexity, you can write 2<sup>O(n)</sup>. This includes exponential functions with arbitrary bases, e.g. the function f(n) = 16<sup>n</sup> since this equals 2<sup>4n</sup>, and 4n is in the set O(n). It's an [abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation), since raising the number 2 to the power of a set of functions doesn't really make sense in this context, but it is common enough to be understood.

Comment: @j.a. The "[O(...) is a set of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Other_notation)" definition is a standard one in computer science, e.g. it's given in [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) (a.k.a. the CLRS textbook). This is the general case - c is a constant, and g(n) is an arbitrary function which is not necessarily linear in n.

Comment: @j.a. It would be a strictly correct statement, but not a good answer to the question; imagine an exam question where you're given some code, and asked *"what is the output when this code is run?"* and you wrote, "it prints some numbers". That may be a true statement, but it's a much weaker statement than if you said what actual numbers it printed, so it's a worse answer. Likewise, if you say that f(n) = 4n is in O(2^n) then you are strictly correct but it is a much weaker statement than you could have made.