# Wondering the time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

In my job I had to implement an algorithm, the specifics details does not matters, but I was unable to have a clear answer about the time complexity of this specific algorithm.

In a nutshell it's look like something like that:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
        for(let k = 0; k < 8; k++ {
            // Do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

What is the time complexity of this algorithm ?

At the beginning I thought it would be something like O(n^3). But the more I think about, the more I think it's actually more a 0(n). Because, even though we have 3 for loop, only one can be of a variable size, the two other are constant.

So what is the actual time complexity of this algorithm ? Is it O(n^3), O(n) or even something else ?

Comment: The outer loop iterates 3 times, for each time its inner loop iterates n times, and for each of these time, the innermost loop iterates 8 times. Therefore you get 3 * n * 8 = 24n which is an O(n).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it would be `O(n)`. You are right.

The total number of execution is `3 * n * 8 = 24*n` where 24 can be ignored for large `n`. So the complexity is `O(n)`

Answer (score 3):

The time complexity of the code is `O(n)`:

As the outer loop iterates a constant number of times, for each time its inner loop iterates `n - 1` times, and for each of these times, the innermost loop iterates a constant number of times.

Therefore you get `3 * (n - 1) * 8 = 24n - 24` and as constants are discarded for big-O notation, you get `O(n)`.

That being said, the time complexity of the code can be affected by the code that runs inside of the innermost loop (i.e the `// Do some stuff` part). If you are only doing a constant number of operations there, the code complexity will not be affected. However, if for example, you sort an array of size n in there, then this will change the time complexity to `n * nlogn`.

Answer (score 3):

**Direct answer**

Besides great answers already given, I'd like you to picture the calculation over each loop:

[image]

Certain implicit rules applied are relative to:

- The complexity of a ***constant*** k is `O(1)`

example: `3 = O(1)`, `8 = O(1)`

- Given high values of a ***variable*** n and a ***constant*** k, the relation is verified: `O(n + k) = O(n) + k = O(n)`

example:  `O(n-1) = O(n) -1 = O(n)`

- Given high values of a ***variable*** n and a ***constant*** k, the relation is verified: `k x O(n) = O(kn) = O(n)`

example:  `3x O(n) = O(3n) = O(n)`

**Extension**

Let's change your loop to have case where you'd have `O(n^3)` as you were wondering:

```
for(let i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
        for(let k = 0; k < n-1; k++ {
            // Do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Because each loop has a complexity of  `O(n)`, we have `O(n) x O(n) x O(n) = O(n^3)`

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity for this code is `O(n)`. Outer and inner loops have constant number of iterations and are independent from the input size (`n`). And constants are discarded for big O notation.

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity will be `O(n)`, because 3 and 8 are constants which can be [ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60059910/17939455). Also, the second loop is going till `n - 1`, where 1 is also ignored. NOTE: All this ignorance of constants is when `n` becomes really large in value.

If inside all these loop a function is called, then the total calls to the function is `n`, but in precise manner total call will be

```
(8 * 3 * n) - ((8 * 3) - 1)
```

Which we ignore in big O notation.

Try this code in `C`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t my_calls = 1;

void call_me(void){
    my_calls += 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t n = 1000; // let n = 1000

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) 
        {
            for(size_t k = 0; k < 8; k++) 
            {
                call_me();
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Total calls %lu\n", my_calls);
    if(my_calls == (8 * 3 * n ) - ((8 * 3) - 1))
        printf("GOOD\n");
    else
        printf("BAD\n");
    return 0;
}
```

[**`LIVE DEMO`**](https://godbolt.org/z/bK6f8nWrv)